# Execute commands in new window of executed program with c code or batch file

Tags: c, batch-file, exe

I have a compiled program (`task.exe`). The result of this program is a new cmd window with specific commands there. I need to execute commands just in that cmd window, that is, I need to send keyboard input to that window. I tried to make something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Start task.exe"); 
    system("task.exe && command ");
    return 0;         
}
```

Guys, could you please help me with this problem. I think maybe I should somehow get the created process, and then work from there.

Comment: Your Task.exe is a command line program? Does it really open it's own cmd window? What do you mean with cmd window? A console window where cmd.exe is running? Or just a console window?

Comment: Yes it is really open in it's own window. Just a console window. So I cannot work with this program with cmd.exe and send there the options. I need just type in this new console window command.

Comment: Please clarify "I need to execute commands just in that cmd window." From your last comment I understand you so that you just want to send keyboard input!?

Comment: Yes I need to send keyboard input there.

Answer (score 0):

You can send keyboard input using the function [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx).

A better, but more complex approach would be using [Microsoft UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee684009(v=VS.85).aspx).